# How do I make my Django dropdown form show items owned by a user and not all users?

Tags: python, django-views, django-forms

I am having trouble displaying items owned only by specific users, rather than each user getting to see all items in my database. Below is an example of a non-superuser who has access to all items in my database when this user should only have access to the ones they created

[image of dropdown menu with all items instead of just some](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFGAR.png)

Below are the Form, View, and Models I have created in attempt to do this.

forms.py

```
class RoutineForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""creates a form for a routine"""
class Meta:
    model = Routine
    fields = ['workout']
    labels = {'workout': 'Workout'}
```

Here is the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
@login_required
def routine(request):
    """display a dropdown of all workouts for a user"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = RoutineForm()
    else:
        form = RoutineForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_routine = form.save(commit=False)
            new_routine.save()
            return redirect('index')
    context = {'workouts':workouts, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'routine_workouts_app/routine.html', context)
```

and finally, the models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Workout(models.Model):
    """A workout group the user will use to workout"""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200) #titles should not be too long
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model"""
        return self.text


class Routine(models.Model):
    """Shows a routine"""
    workout = models.ForeignKey(Workout, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'this is a routine'
```

Am I missing some sort of filter? Something Fundamental? I have been able to filter some other views that I have made. For example:

```
@login_required
def workouts(request):
    """This is the page that will display all the workout groups"""
    workouts = Workout.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('text') #filter by user ownership
    context = {'workouts': workouts}
    return render(request, 'routine_workouts_app/workouts.html', context)
```

on line 4 of this snippet, I have successfully filtered items that only belong to a specific user. But this is not a form, just a display on an html file. I have tried to put a similar line in the routine view function but it did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a parameter to the constructor of the `RoutineForm`, that will filter the queryset specified to link to a `Workout`. This thus means that the form looks like:

```
class RoutineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """creates a form for a routine"""
    
    def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['workout'].queryset = Workout.objects.filter(owner=user)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Routine
        fields = ['workout']
        labels = {'workout': 'Workout'}
```

In the view, we then can construct a `Form` where we pass the logged in user to the constructor of the form:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def routine(request):
    """display a dropdown of all workouts for a user"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = RoutineForm(user=request.user)
    else:
        form = RoutineForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.owner = request.user
            new_routine = form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    context = {'workouts':workouts, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'routine_workouts_app/routine.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working properly now!